# Best way to create panoramas on iPhone?

Tags: ios, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to create panoramas in an iOS app by stitching together several images (similar to an app like PhotoSynth).  I've looked all over and haven't yet found a winning implementation strategy.  Here are the things I've looked into:

1) Linking OpenCV for iOS and implementing stitching and the panorama creation process myself.

2) Getting panotools to work on iOS and using the PT* functions to produce the panorama

Am I on the right track?  Are there any simpler ways of implementing this?

Obviously a good quality out-of-the-box solution is preferred, but if there isn't one, which of the two above (or another) strategies would be best for a CV novice?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should try to understand [how to build panoramas](ftp://ftp.research.microsoft.com/users/hshum/.../MSR9723.pdf) from a technical stand point before you implement the software on the IPhone.

**EDIT:** March 2013 I'm pretty sure the link I gave worked in January 2012, but it is indeed now broken, Alternative links:
https://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse455/06wi/readings/szeliskiShum97.pdf
http://www.multires.caltech.edu/teaching/courses/3DP/papers/SchumSzeliski.pdf

Comment: @Oleg Trakhman: I've edited the answer and updated the links.